# DRCSIM: drcsim-nightly can't roslaunch either

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drcsim-nightly
```

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

dies with the messages

```
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 66.93.172.108

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:89] Connection Manager is not running
[ WARN] [1365984890.721418172]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1365984890.721556925]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1365984890.721585357]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1365984890.721623327]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/cga/.ros/log/7c7c454a-a561-11e2-9900-d4bed9fd5ae1/gazebo-2*.log
```

Interestingly,

```
gazebo
```

works, as does our code that does not use ROS:

```
gazebo world
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2388/drcsim:-drcsim-nightly-can%27t-roslaunch-either/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm unable to reproduce this problem.  Is it still happening?  If not, it was likely a temporary instability in the nightly packages.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0